# Can I retrieve all the results from a groupby?

Tags: pandas

Suppose I group my data like

`df.groupby(['a','b','c'])`

Is there a way to `get_group` for every group in `a`, and a specific value of `b` and `c`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you think select columns `a` and `b` in custom function?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],
                   'b':[4,5,6],
                   'c':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6]})

print (df)
   D  E  a  b  c
0  1  5  1  4  7
1  3  3  2  5  8
2  5  6  3  6  9


def f(x):
#    print (x)
    print (x[['a','b']])
    return x[['a','b']]

print (df.groupby(['a','b','c']).apply(f))

   a  b
0  1  4
   a  b
0  1  4
   a  b
1  2  5
   a  b
2  3  6
   a  b


   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

---

Or maybe you need [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
print (df.groupby(['a','b','c']).filter(lambda x: (x.b == 4) & (x.c == 7)))
   D  E  a  b  c
0  1  5  1  4  7
```

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your question. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

```
[name for name,group in df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])]
```